# Can not deploy my application on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Here is output (error lines):

```
INFO [56c27871] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/demas/stackify-node`/shared /home/demas/stackify-node`/releases as demas@ubuntuservices.cloudapp.net
DEBUG [56c27871] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/demas/stackify-node`/shared /home/demas/stackify-node`/releases
DEBUG [56c27871]    bash: /shared: No such file or directory
INFO [56c27871] Finished in 0.142 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [dcbc8031] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /home/demas/stackify-node`/current/REVISION ] as demas@ubuntuservices.cloudapp.net
DEBUG [dcbc8031] Command: [ -f /home/demas/stackify-node`/current/REVISION ]
DEBUG [dcbc8031]    bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
DEBUG [dcbc8031]    bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
DEBUG [dcbc8031] Finished in 0.132 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [e46d75ae] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /home/demas/stackify-node`/repo/HEAD ] as demas@ubuntuservices.cloudapp.net
DEBUG [e46d75ae] Command: [ -f /home/demas/stackify-node`/repo/HEAD ]
DEBUG [e46d75ae]    bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
DEBUG [e46d75ae]    bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
DEBUG [e46d75ae] Finished in 0.133 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [a70addc0] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /home/demas/stackify-node`; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/demas/stackify-node`'" 1>&2; false; fi as demas@ubuntuservices.cloudapp.net
DEBUG [a70addc0] Command: if test ! -d /home/demas/stackify-node`; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/demas/stackify-node`'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [a70addc0]    bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
DEBUG [a70addc0]    bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Here is full output: http://pastebin.com/XE2ApRvz

How can I fix it ?

**Update:**

Here is my deploy.rb: http://pastebin.com/5cp5tkzn

Comment: Looks like a Capistrano configuration problem. Can you share with us the `deploy.rb` file? Especially anything related to `deploy_to`.

Comment: I have update my question.  Here is deploy.rb http://pastebin.com/5cp5tkzn

Comment: Remove \` from set :deploy_to, '/home/demas/stackify-node`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the limited information you most likely have a line like:

```
set :deploy_to, "/home/demas/stackify-node`"
```

Remove the ` at the end.

If this is not the problem, share your `deploy.rb` and `deploy/production.rb` files so we can review your Capistrano configuration.